# cloned official google drive android demo not working

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

There are quite a few similar questions / problems on the net unresolved.

1. I just cloned the sample, using android studio
2. According to readme ->

> register an OAuth 2.0 client for the package
>   `com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo` with your own debug keys
>   and set any resource IDs to those that you have access to.    Resource
>   ID definitions are on:
>   * com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo.BaseDemoActivity.EXISTING_FOLDER_ID
>
> - com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo.BaseDemoActivity.EXISTING_FILE_ID

3. So OAuth 2.0 key done, change of folder id  and file id done
4. Add Permissions

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
   ```
5. Add Intent

   ```
       <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.APP_ID" android:value="id=66xxxxxxxxxxx" />
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.DRIVE_OPEN" />
           <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk.66xxxxxxxxxxx" />
           <data android:mimeType="image/png" />
           <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
           <data android:mimeType="image/jpg" />
       </intent-filter>
   ```

So, Run the code in Emulator and real device,

```
30570-30570/com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo I/BaseDriveActivity: GoogleApiClient connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{3b3293e8: android.os.BinderProxy@2b09da01}, message=null}

30570-30570/com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo I/BaseDriveActivity: GoogleApiClient connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null, message=null}

30570-30570/com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo E/GoogleApiAvailability: Internal error occurred. Please see logs for detailed information
```

Really no idea whats going wrong.

Comment: Looks like you need to add a way to get your user signed in before trying to access their drive.

Answer (score 2):

I just skipped your #4 and #5 step.

Just enable Drive Api form Library.

[image: Google APIs > Library > Drive API]

Answer (score 0):

[ConnectionResult](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult) states that these error could be encountered on the following instances:

- [SIGN_IN_REQUIRED](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#SIGN_IN_REQUIRED)

  > The client attempted to connect to the service but the user is not signed in. The client may choose to continue without using the API.
- [INTERNAL_ERROR](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#INTERNAL_ERROR)

  > An internal error occurred. Retrying should resolve the problem.

You may want to also check this step-by-step [Google Drive Android integration tutorial](https://www.numetriclabz.com/integrate-google-drive-in-android-tutorial) and see if you have missed something.

Lastly, these GitHub posts might also help:

- [GoogleApiClient connection failed #49](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/issues/49)
- [not woking #7](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart/issues/7)
- [Unknown issue with Google play services #2](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart/issues/2)